How to dynamically inject a repository in Nestjs
I want to create a service that receives an entity and creates a repository.
This is my attempt:
export class MyService<T extends ObjectLiteral> {
  protected repo: Repository<T>;

  constructor(entity: T) {
   let token = getRepositoryToken(entity);
   this.repo = InjectRepository(entity)(this, 'repo');
  }

// methods
}

Usage:
let service = new MyService(MyEntity)
service.repo.findmany()


I think you can help @Jay McDoniel

why don't you use BaseEntity in typeorm

does it help to dynamically inject a repository in the service class? @HaiAlison

yeah you don't need to inject any repository at all, just use YourModel.find()

this is what i use:
import { BaseEntity } from 'typeorm';

export class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
 //your columns...
}

and your service when get a query

export class MyService<T extends ObjectLiteral> {

  async getAll(){
    const results = await MyEntity.find();
    //...
  }
}


awsome, but I need to have this.repo
